# CSS :hover outside a div

Tags: html, css

So I have my navigation with this code

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="photos">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="arrow">

</div>
```

Whenever I :hover any a with class, I want my #arrow to move.

Is there a way to do that? Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: How do you mean 'move'? Shake? Move to the <li> being hovered over?

Comment: You can't `:hover` your `#arrow` and `id` it too.

Comment: Horizontally? vertically? I see you know about jQuery, so you could rephrase your question cause as @Johnathan said, you can do it with javascript.

Comment: @Sp4cecat - When I hover an anchor. The id #arrow will move horizontally.

Comment: We can show you a jQuery way, but that won't suit with your Question at all. So I think you can create a new one.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible with CSS alone. You would need some dynamic scripting to accomplish that. Using `:hover`, you can manipulate properties on the element being hovered, as well as its children/grandchildren. `#arrow`, however, is not nested within any of your list items, and as such their `:hover` state cannot dictate styles to the arrow element - not directly, at least.

As stated, you *can* accomplish this with some dynamic scripting. For instance, the following jQuery will accomplish the effect you're after:

```
$("ul").on("mouseenter mouseleave", "li", function(e){
   e.type === "mouseenter"
       ? $("#arrow").stop().animate({ 
           left:    $(this).offset().left, 
           width:   $(this).outerWidth(),
           opacity: 1           
       }, 500 )
       : $("#arrow").stop().animate({ 
           left:    0, 
           width:   $("ul li:first").outerWidth(),
           opacity: 0
       }, 750 );       
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZvqPZ/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with CSS as has been stated. You can used jQuery, e.g.  Use css class to specifiy the positions and change between the classes on hover using jquery.

**jQuery**:

```
$("li a").hover(    
  function () {    /* on hover over*/
    $("#arrow").addClass("moved-pos");
  },
  function () {    /* on hover out*/
    $("#arrow").removeClass("moved-pos");
  }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#arrow{ /*set original position for arrow */ }
#arrow.moved-pos{ /*set new position here */ }
```

(note this code is untested)